# adding media file durations as strings in "hh:mm:ss" format

Tags: powershell

I extract videoclip duration from a .mp4 file as a string in "hh:mm:ss" format:

```
$duration = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27)
```

I want to get the total duration of all videoclips in a folder.
  How can I sum up these durations without extracting the seconds, minutes each time ?

Answer (score 1):

Cast the duration as a `[TimeSpan]` and then add it with the others:

```
$totalDuration = New-TimeSpan
# making up a loop since you didn't provide one
foreach ($shellfile in $Files) { 
    $duration = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27)
    $totalDuration += ([TimeSpan]$duration)
}
```

Comment: thanks @briantist, it does the job; casting the string as TimeSpan is nice and efficient.